# How to make for_each takes lambda function that take 2 arguments?

Tags: c++, lambda, foreach

I'm trying to make `lambda` function that takes 2 parameters and return the sum of them, and pass this function to `for_each` loop to add each 2 elements together.
But since `for_each` let the function work on the current element, I can't add the current and the next element together!

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <int> v = {1, 2, 4, 54 ,64, 32, 43, 3};
    auto add = [](int x, int y) {cout <<  (x+y) << endl;};
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), add);
}
```

But this gives error, I tried to handle this manually by :

```
vector <int> v = {1, 2, 4, 54 ,64, 32, 43, 3};
    auto add = [](auto x) {auto s = x + *(&x+1); //adding the current element and the next elemnt.    
                            cout << s << endl;};
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), add) ;
```

output :

```
7077509
7077510
7077512
7077562
7077572
7077540
7077551
7077511
```

I don't know from where this extra `7077508` number come from ! and this will not work if the container is not associative.
So how to make this `add` function takes 2 parameters.

Comment: You can't have the lambda take two parameters because `std::for_each` passes only one parameter to the lambda it calls. That's what it does. You cannot change that. `x` is a passed-by-value parameter to the lambda. It's not the value in the array. Its address is not the address of the value in the array. Although it's possible to make that parameter a reference, and thus the actual value in the array, this will still be undefined behavior, as shown. You need to figure out how to do what you want to do without using `std::for_each` because it doesn't work this way.

Comment: ok, got it thanks.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik why would it be UB if the lambda took the argument by reference? (considering the range ending at `v.end() - 1`, so it doesn't access out of bounds)

Comment: Well, @Fureeish, because that's not where the range ends in the shown code. It ends at `v.end()`, and clearly not at `v.end()-1`. You must've noted the ***as shown***, that was clearly stated in my comment.